# SPListItem.Attachments - what type cast?

Tags: 2010, development, splistitem, attachments

When iterating through a `SPListItem`s `SPAttachmentCollection` what type cast am I supposed to use? `SPFile` or `SPFileStream` or something else?

I want to display the item's filename and when it was uploaded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> "the SPAttachmentCollection is simply an array of strings representing
>   the file name of each attachment"

from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1334893/sharepoint-spattachmentcollection-a-collection-of-what-exactly

Here, from the same link, is an example of usage:

```
var attachments in item.Attachments;
foreach (string fileName in attachments)
{
    SPFile file = web.GetFile(attachments.UrlPrefix + fileName);
    // Do something ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
   //To get the SPFile reference to the attachment just use this code
   SPFile attachmentFile = web.GetFile(attachmentAbsURL);

   // To read the file content simply use this code
   Stream stream = attachmentFile.OpenBinaryStream();
   StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream);
   String fileContent = reader.ReadToEnd();
```

Comment: Seems a bit complicated to use a StreamReader ;)

Comment: @RobertLindgren I still appreciate it though in case I need for later on :D

Comment: Yeah for downloading the files to the browser in an .ashx it is perfect :)